# How to search specific SKU in magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento-2.1.7

In search bar when i am searching a product using sku (100.40.10),

It displays all the product whose sku is having prefix (100.xx.xx) ,

But i only want it to fetch whose sku is (100.40.10).

Comment: use exact search not %like%

Comment: Could you please explain this in detail, like which file needs to override in Magento2

Comment: I referred this blog : http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-get-one-search-result-by-sku
Bu do not get success

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1):

By default, while searching for a product through catalog search, Magento uses all attributes for which the value of **`Use in Search`** is set to **`Yes`**.

If your Magento is not able to search a unique product when your search is being done by SKU, it means there is at least one attribute which is being used for search and the value of the search string is same for some products for that particular attribute.

You may check for the attributes for which the value of **`Use in Search`** is set to **`Yes`**. Set the value of **`Use in Search`** to **`No`** for all the attributes except SKU.

After that Reindex and check again. Once the search starts working as expected, you can set the value of **`Use in Search`** to Yes for the attributes which you want to include in search.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 has feature to set which kind of search you want, but in Magento 2 that feature removed so you need to customize that magento-search module
Just create Plugin the customize and change the match strategie `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match` and use around Plugin Function technique :

```
<?php

namespace Test\OneSku\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\FieldInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\ScoreBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Query\BoolExpression;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\QueryInterface as RequestQueryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Preprocessor\PreprocessorInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext as FulltextResource;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection as AttributeCollection;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Test\OneSku\Helper\Data as OneSkuData;

class Match extends \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match
{
    const SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = '-+~/\\<>\'":*$#@()!,.?`=%&^';
    const MINIMAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 3;

    private $replaceSymbols = [];
    private $resolver;
    private $fulltextHelper;
    private $fulltextSearchMode;
    protected $preprocessors;
    private $attributeCollection;
    private $fulltextResource;
    private $storeManager;
    private $_resource;
    protected $dataHelper;

    public function __construct(
        OneSkuData $dataHelper,
        AttributeCollection $attributeCollection,
        FulltextResource $fulltextResource,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManage,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        ResolverInterface $resolver,
        Fulltext $fulltextHelper,
        $fulltextSearchMode = Fulltext::FULLTEXT_MODE_BOOLEAN,
        array $preprocessors = []
    ) {
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
        $this->replaceSymbols = str_split(self::SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, 1);
        $this->fulltextHelper = $fulltextHelper;
        $this->fulltextSearchMode = $fulltextSearchMode;
        $this->preprocessors = $preprocessors;
        $this->attributeCollection = $attributeCollection;
        $this->fulltextResource = $fulltextResource;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManage;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($resolver,$fulltextHelper, $fulltextSearchMode, $preprocessors);
    }

    public function aroundBuild($matcher, $build, $scoreBuilder, $select, $query, $conditionType)
    {
        $resultSku = 0;
        $queryValue = $this->prepareQuery($query->getValue(), $conditionType);
        $fieldList = [];
        foreach ($query->getMatches() as $match) {
            $fieldList[] = $match['field'];
        }
        $resolvedFieldList = $this->resolver->resolve($fieldList);
        $fieldIds = [];
        $columns = [];
        foreach ($resolvedFieldList as $field) {
            if ($field->getType() === FieldInterface::TYPE_FULLTEXT && $field->getAttributeId()) {
                $fieldIds[] = $field->getAttributeId();
            }
            $column = $field->getColumn();
            $columns[$column] = $column;
        }
        if ($this->dataHelper->allowExtension()) {
            $attribute = $this->attributeCollection->getItemByColumnValue('attribute_code', 'sku');
            $attributeId = $attribute ? $attribute->getId() : 0;
            if ($attributeId != 0) {
                $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
                $mainFullTextScope = $this->fulltextResource->getMainTable() . "_scope" . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
                $tblFullTextScope = $connection->getTableName($mainFullTextScope);
                $resultSku = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT count(entity_id) FROM `' . $tblFullTextScope . '` WHERE attribute_id=' . $attributeId . ' And data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'');
            }
        }
        if ($resultSku == 1) {
            $matchQuery = 'data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'';
        } else {
            $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
                $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
            );
        }
        $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
                $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
        );
        $scoreBuilder->addCondition($matchQuery, true);
        if ($fieldIds) {
            $matchQuery = sprintf('(%s AND search_index.attribute_id IN (%s))', $matchQuery, implode(',', $fieldIds));
        }
        $select->where($matchQuery);
        return $select;
    }
}
```

In this class we have added some line to test of SKU with some reference is exist by example in table `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` (related to store id 1)

```
$attribute = $this->attributeCollection->getItemByColumnValue('attribute_code', 'sku');
$attributeId = $attribute ? $attribute->getId() : 0;
if ($attributeId != 0) {
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $mainFullTextScope = $this->fulltextResource->getMainTable() . "_scope" . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $tblFullTextScope = $connection->getTableName($mainFullTextScope);
    $resultSku = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT count(entity_id) FROM `' . $tblFullTextScope . '` WHERE attribute_id=' . $attributeId . ' And data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'');
}
```

If yes we change the clause were to be strict equal without the Boolean match or like.

```
if ($resultSku == 1) {
    $matchQuery = 'data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'';
} else {
    $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
        $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
    );
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: clear the cache and reindex, this will work

Comment: http://pebblenew.lnx-local.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=100.30.46

Comment: I am using above example but not getting expected result.

Comment: can you remove the other attribute from search(Use in Search to No for all the attributes except SKU) and try

Comment: I tried that too , but no luck :(

Comment: oh, don't forget to reindex the data

Comment: "solved this with installing ElasticSearch. I did find some SKU searches were returning results, but not all. Elastic solved all the issues." found this you can try this too

Comment: This solution will not work for Magento2.4.x because Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match doesn't exists in latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Magento Version (2.4.x) this can be fixed in file -

Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\MatchQuery.php

Line no 88 add below code-

```
if ($matchKey != 'match_phrase_prefix') {
    $matchQuery['operator'] = "AND";
}
```

[image]

Note: Try to overwrite this file in your module.