# Shash (/) in SKU is stopped search in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search

I have an issue with Magento search . I have a slashes in sku , and when i am trying to search specific product for example "ABCD/4" it shows ABCD/4 and ABCD/2
Its magento problem?
[image]

Please help , Thanks!

Comment: its magento2 default function, check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229573/how-to-search-specific-sku-in-magento2)

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behavior

ABCD/4 treated as "ABCD" and "4" and by default MySQL full-text search skip word less than 3 symbols

Comment: Thanks , but the same is with ABCD/4444 . How can i make search by full SKU? Thanks

Comment: It's because Magento finds all products that contain at least one word and order them by relevance