# Magento 2: How to Achieve Partial Match Search for SKU and Other Attributes?

Tags: catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento2-4-5

I'm encountering a challenge with the search functionality in Magento 2 and could use your expertise. Specifically, the issue revolves around partial match searches, especially concerning the SKU attribute.

**Issue Description:**

- When I search with the exact SKU (e.g., `"ML1797"`), the product is
  retrieved as expected in the search results.
- However, when I perform a search with a partial SKU (e.g., `"1797"`),
  no results are found, which is not the desired outcome.

**Objective:**

- I want to configure or customize the search functionality so that partial SKU searches return relevant results.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've ensured that the SKU attribute is set to `"Use in Search"` under `Stores > Attributes > Product > SKU`.
- I've reindexed and cleared cache after making configuration changes.
- I attempted to create a plugin for `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match`, but it seems like I'm unable to find this class.
- I've also explored some GitHub and Magento StackExchange threads for insights

  1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9988#issuecomment-1637645647
  2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/367950/109248

**Additional Context:**

- Magento Version: *2.4.5-p1*
- Search Engine: *Elasticsearch 7*
- Additional Search Module : *MGS/InstantSearch*
- No relevant errors in log files.

**Questions:**

- Is there a configuration or best practice approach to achieve partial match searches for SKU (and potentially other attributes) in Magento 2?
- If customization is required, could you provide a guideline on how to approach this, especially considering the Elasticsearch engine?

Any insights, advice, or shared experiences would be incredibly helpful!

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Sure!